# Is this flow possible?

Tags: erc-20

There are three EOAs: `A`, `B`, and `C`.  `B` has no token.

- TX1: `A` call `approve` `B` for 100 token.
- TX2: `B` call `transferFrom` for 100 token from `A` to `B`.
- TX3: `B` call `transfer` 100 token to `C`.

If these three transactions are included in same block, TX3 can success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in case the transactions will be included in the same block **in proper order**, they will be successfully executed.

Moreover, all three operations could be done in a single transaction, in case both, `A` and `B` are contracts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you let me know the flow more specifically how to make it in single transaction?

Comment: What if both A and B are EOA, but C is contract?